# Date in a loop - display the first / skip the rest

Tags: php, for-loop, while-loop, iteration

A chat has a message date from an SQL database. The timestamp is formatted with php date:

```
 $dateabove = date("d.m.Y : H:i",$row['message_time']);
```

The date is in a loop (while):-

Today has to show today and yesterday has to show yesterday. Then only the date comes.
It should look something like `Whatsapp`.

Example:-
( $dateabove - $row['message_text'] ) :

```
me: 28.10.2020 : 13:75  - Hello

you: 28.10.2020 : 14:01  - Hello

me: 31.10.2020 : 11:01  - How are you?

you: 31.10.2020 : 12:01  - fine

me: 01.11.2020 : 10:05  -  Where you from?
```

**Should look like:**

```
*28.10.2020*

me: 28.10.2020 : 13:75  - Hello

you: 28.10.2020 : 14:01  - Hello


*Yesterday*

me: 31.10.2020 : 11:01  - How are you?

you: 31.10.2020 : 12:01  - fine


*Today*

me: 01.11.2020 : 10:05  -  Where you from?
```

The problem is, how can you only display the date above the first message within the loop and not on the subsequent messages on that day.

This is how my loop looks like:

```
while ($row = $db->sql_fetchrow($result));

for ($i = 0, $size = sizeof($rowset); $i < $size; $i++)
{
echo $row['message_time']);
}
```

Comment: Please provide more context by showing us the code which generates your current output.

Comment: Store the date during iteration and if the same as previous don't display. Probably something like `if($row['date'] != $last_iteration_date) { echo '....';}` Your `should be` has the date in every example though, so I presume you are just trying to add `Today/yesterday/etc` headings once per group..

Comment: @RoAchterberg the code is to long, I tried to make the answer as short as possible.  how to get the last_iteration_date?

Comment: @Lars Vegas All the chats & Dates are stored in the database??

Comment: @KUMAR yes, all chats and dates are in the database and they are all in while loop already. Thank you very much for help. I think its no problem for me to get the yesterday and the today stuff. For me its just important to get the date only above the first post of each day and skip the rest.

Comment: @Lars Vegas  please show us your while loop code please so we will help you..

Comment: @KUMAR ok, I have updated my answer. Please have a look at the bottom.

Comment: @KUMAR thank you very much for the edit. I cant aproove it but it looks fine for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a little demonstration of one possible approach. Please read the comments for a detailed explanation of what's going on. See [this eval](https://3v4l.org/IGNhd) for a live demo. You can play around with it and you can see its output.

```
<?php

// Current time as UNIX timestamp.
$now = time();
// Find yesterday's date by subtracting one day ('P1D') from today (new DateTime).
$yesterday = (new DateTime)->sub(new DateInterval('P1D'));

// Mock a bunch of messages.
$messages =
[
    // Yesterday's messages
    [
        'user_id' => 1,
        'user_natural_name' => 'me',
        // format('U') will give us UNIX timestamp.
        'timestamp' => $yesterday->setTime(19, 0)->format('U'),
        'text' => 'Hiya'
    ],
    [
        'user_id' => 2,
        'user_natural_name' => 'you',
        'timestamp' => $yesterday->setTime(19, 5)->format('U'),
        'text' => 'Hey, how are you?'
    ],
    
    // Today's messages
    [
        'user_id' => 1,
        'user_natural_name' => 'me',
        'timestamp' => $now,
        'text' => 'Hello'
    ],
    [
        'user_id' => 2,
        'user_natural_name' => 'you',
        // Three seconds later.
        'timestamp' => $now + 3,
        'text' => 'Hi'
    ],
    [
        'user_id' => 1,
        'user_natural_name' => 'me',
        'timestamp' => $now + 6,
        'text' => 'What\'s up'
    ],
    [
        'user_id' => 2,
        'user_natural_name' => 'you',
        'timestamp' => $now + 9,
        'text' => 'Not much'
    ],
    [
        'user_id' => 1,
        'user_natural_name' => 'me',
        'timestamp' => $now + 12,
        'text' => 'Awesome'
    ]
];

// If $lastWindowDate differs from the current message in the queue,
// then display it as a separator between day-to-day conversations.
$lastWindowDate = NULL;

// $index will tell us whether we already had output from earlier days so we can
// show a separating newline.
foreach ($messages as $index => $message)
{
    // Window as a perspective on the message flow.
    $windowDate = date('Ymd', $message['timestamp']);
    // If current message's date is not last message's date, then output it to the user.
    if ($windowDate !== $lastWindowDate)
    {
        // Translate today's YMD and yesterday's YMD to something more naturally interpretable for a better UX.

        // Compare against current message's datestamp.
        switch (date('Ymd', $message['timestamp']))
        {
            // date('Ymd') without a second argument defaults to 'today'.
            case date('Ymd'):
                $dateLabel = 'today';
            break;
            // Format $yesterday DateTime as Ymd.
            case $yesterday->format('Ymd'):
                $dateLabel = 'yesterday';
            break;
            // Neither? Pass through as numeric date.
            default:
                $dateLabel = $windowDate;
            break;
        }
        
        // Already had previous output? Show a newline now as visual separator.
        if ($index)
            echo "\n";

        // Output date label at the top of message list for that day.
        echo "$dateLabel\n";
        
        // Reset the last date seen for the conditional to work.
        $lastWindowDate = $windowDate;
    }
 
    // Show message.   
    echo "{$message['user_natural_name']}: " . date('d.m.Y : H:i', $message['timestamp']) . " - {$message['text']}\n";
}
```

Comment: Great, let me know how it turns out.

Comment: Well, your demo works very well and this is exactly what I am looking for but in my case it doestn skip the date. I dont want waste your time, because you made me already a nice example. Maybe I can show you my hole script?

Comment: @LarsVegas, if you meant that I omitted the date in the message output then you were right. I updated my answer to include the date so it better mimics your example output. If you found my answer helpful, then please consider marking it as accepted :).

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick reply. No, I meant that I cant adapt your example to my code. Anyways, I will accept your answer because its my fault, when your answer doest not match my problem. But maybe you can have a look at my code? I paste it to here, please have a look at $row['message_time'] in the loop. https://pastebin.com/xwzgQ1jx

Comment: I have accept your answer now but like I said, it would be great when you can have a look at my code and provide me a solution?

Comment: Thank you. I saw your code but am having a little trouble locating the context you provided in your initial question. Where do I find the `while` and the `for` you mention? Are you sure you've provided the right pastebin?

Comment: Thank you very much for getting into. Yes, its the correct paste bin. Please see line 70 for the while. This adds the dataset from the SQL Querie while ($row = $db->sql_fetchrow($result)); After this line, you can use $row['message_time']. The next important line is 96. There the "for" starts.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223947/discussion-between-ro-achterberg-and-lars-vegas).

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for your offer. I fixed it by myself. Your example helped me alot.

Comment: @LarsVegas, even better! Good luck with your application.